# gclient runhooks fails

Tags: build-process, chromium

I'm trying to build Chrome under windows, I got the chromium trunk using tortoiseSVN and I believe I got everything correctly, but when I run "gclient runhooks" I get the error: "Error: client not configured; see 'gclient config'".

Now, I know that it happens because I don't have a ".gclient" file on the same directory, but I couldn't find .gclient file anywhere in the project. I tried to create .gclient file myself but it says there's a solution missing.

I'm probably missing something, can anyone help me with that? I'm pretty stuck!
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The above solution is out-dated. Running with the SVN repository results in:

```
Error: 
The chromium code repository has migrated completely to git.
Your SVN-based checkout is now obsolete; you need to create a brand-new
git checkout by following these instructions:

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code
```

Now you need to create a .gclient file like this

```
solutions = [
  {
    "managed": False,
    "name": "src",
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git",
    "custom_deps": {},
    "deps_file": ".DEPS.git",
    "safesync_url": "",
  },
]
```

and do:

```
gclient sync
```

Answer (score 16):

```
gclient config http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src
gclient runhooks
```

Or make a .gclient file with the following content, which skips the huge amount of webkit layout tests

```
solutions = [
  { "name"        : "src",
    "url"         : "http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src",
    "deps_file"   : "DEPS",
    "managed"     : True,
    "custom_deps" : {
      "src/third_party/WebKit/LayoutTests": None,
      "src/chrome_frame/tools/test/reference_build/chrome": None,
      "src/chrome/tools/test/reference_build/chrome_mac": None,
      "src/chrome/tools/test/reference_build/chrome_win": None,
      "src/chrome/tools/test/reference_build/chrome_linux": None,
    },
    "safesync_url": "",
  },
]
```

Comment: But how do you set this now? which was done in old `echo "target_os = ['android', 'unix']" >> .gclient`

Answer (score 4):

Chromium does not include a preconfigured .gclient file for the Chromium build and does not automatically handle Visual Studio versioning changes and default Deploy toolkit hints. After you have successfully downloaded the deploy tools and the chromium source code as provided at [chromium.org](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) perform the following in the root directory where your deploy_tools and src code is located.

**NOTE : If you receive errors try to start a new command prompt session and try again.**

```
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION = 2015
gclient config https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git
gclient sync
gclient runhooks
cd src
ninja -C out\Debug chrome
```

The build will take some time gclient runhooks should generate the build folder.