# Electron Build ERROR at //v8/BUILD.gn:503:30: Undefined identifier

Tags: electron, chromium, gn

I'm trying to build electron source using command -

```
gn gen out/Testing --args="import(\"//electron/build/args/testing.gn\")"
```

Keep getting this error -

```
ERROR at //v8/BUILD.gn:503:30: Undefined identifier
if (!is_component_build && is_electron_build) {
                           ^----------------
See //BUILD.gn:219:7: which caused the file to be included.
  "//v8:gn_all",
  ^------------
```

I couldn't figure out what I'm missing. I checked again, all the instructions and requirements, all good. Looks like it is pointing to `is_electron_build`. I don't know where this is coming from.

I'm following this https://www.electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-gn

Comment: most probably `is_electron_build` is not defined at `BUILD.gn`. There are so many with same name. Trying to get the exact file.

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions properly as specified in that page? `gclient sync` steps are necessary too as it will download Chromium's third-party dependencies

Comment: @Asesh I did it earlier. Run it again. this time it showed to delete list of files which are not required or run `gclient sync -D` . After running it, now it shows client not configured. Many files and folders were missing. I did git `reset --hard` . Now all file seems to be there but still getting client not configured error.

Comment: This might help you with that client issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684282/gclient-runhooks-fails

Comment: Thanks. But I have restarted all process again. Now its working. But in another problem.

Comment: Build config `gn gen out/Testing --args="import(\"//electron/build/args/testing.gn\")"` was successfull. But now this error comes `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gen/third_party/dom_distiller_js/test_sample_json_converter.h'` when I try to build `gn gen out/Testing --args="import(\"//electron/build/args/testing.gn\") $GN_EXTRA_ARGS"`

Comment: You should run those `gclient sync` commands as mentioned in that page